# Having blueprint in features xml

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf

I am looking for a way to include a blueprint directly in a features xml file; I looked at the feature's xsd, it allows to include bundle, feature, condition, config but I don't find a way to include a blueprint directly. I am deploying my bundles using the features so I cannot drop the blueprints directly to the deploy folder - 've to use some features to deploy it. Currently, I created a bundle just to include the blueprint. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I created a bundle just to include the blueprint.

That is the way. If you have experience with blueprint, it should not be hard to read the chapter *"121 Blueprint Container Specification"* of [OSGi Enterprise Specification](https://osgi.org/download/r6/osgi.enterprise-6.0.0.pdf). You will hardly find any other way based on the specification.